# Get the values of Standard Drop Down list in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddl, formcollection

I am using a method that generate my questions and answers i mean every questions appear in view and the answers of this question are put to the DDL as you can see here :

```
 public string GenerateHtmlCode()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            List<ExecutiveOfficer> executiveOfficers = executiveOfficerRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            List<Indicator> indicators = indicatorRepository.GetAll().ToList();

            foreach (ExecutiveOfficer executiveOfficer in executiveOfficers)
            {
                result += "<div style='width:100%;float:right;'><span>" + executiveOfficer.ExecutiveOfficerText +
                         "</span><span style='float:left'>" +
                         GenerateAnswer(indicatorRepository.FindBy(i => i.ExecutiveOfficerId == executiveOfficer.Id
                                                                  ).ToList(), executiveOfficer.Id) + "</span></div>";
            }


            return result;
        }
```

In my create method in controller i pass the string to `viewbag`  as you can see here :

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(int preliminaryId)
        {
            ViewBag.preliminaryId = preliminaryId;
            ViewBag.pageGenarator = objScoreRepository.GenerateHtmlCode();
           // List<ExecutiveOfficer> executiveOfficer = objScoreRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            //ViewBag.executiveOfficerName = new SelectList(executiveOfficer, "Id", "ExecutiveOfficerText");
            return View("Create");
        }
```

My html code :

```
</span><span style='float:left'><select id='1'><option value='value1'>displaytext</option></select></span>
```

As you can see in the above code the question with `id=1` and value `value1` and `displaytext`  is generated in my `httppost create controller` i need to get the `questionId`  i mean `1` and the value of that i mean `value1` .i googled it and i found something about `form collection` but i don't know how can i do that ?

Every ideas  will be appreciated.

Best regards

```
 public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            ??????get value and question id to save 

            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Score");
        }
```

Html create view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutIdeaOtherPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.pageGenarator)

    <div class="buttonPossion">
                <input type="submit" value="????? ???????" Class="buttonSave" />
            </div>
}
```

Comment: can you please view your html code...?

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam ti tried the Dawid Dziadkiewicz answer but the form collection returns no records

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use this code it iterate over all formCollection items.

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
{
   foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
   {
       var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
       // save value
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Create", "Score");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dawid ,so how can i get the question iD?

Comment: It should be in the 'key' value.

Comment: I did that but the formcollection doesn't provide any values

Comment: No values come from my html page instead using key i used allkeys .but no values come from the html

Comment: You should add name attribute to select: <select id='1' name="1">

Comment: Thank you now my formcollection can get the name of the ddl i mean it contains "1" but how can i access the value of my ddl?

Comment: var value = formCollection[key]; where key is in your example "1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the value of control in the formcollection

```
formCollection["1"]
```

Html code:-

```
<span style='float:left'><select id='1' name="1"><option value='value1'>displaytext</option></select></span>
```

Your code becomes

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        String Val1 = formCollection["1"].value;
    }
```